# How to separate/filter English text from Chinese in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, function, filter

I am working on a project that includes multiples Excel files with cells containing English, Chinese, or both English and Chinese.

I need to keep the rows that are completely in Chinese and put them first. Then, I need lines with both Chinese characters and English. And only then those that are in English only.

I came across the following 3 functions that could help me mark the content accordingly, yet they do not seem to be working as expected, and I cannot figure out why.

```
Function ExtractChn(txt As String)
Dim i As Integer
Dim ChnTxt As String
For i = 1 To Len(txt)
    If Asc(Mid(txt, i, 1)) < 0 Then
        ChnTxt = ChnTxt & Mid(txt, i, 1)
    End If
Next i
ExtractChn = ChnTxt
End Function

Function ExtractEng(txt As String)
Dim i As Integer
Dim EngTxt As String
For i = 1 To Len(txt)
    If Asc(Mid(txt, i, 1)) >= 0 Then
        EngTxt = EngTxt & Mid(txt, i, 1)
    End If
Next i
ExtractEng = EngTxt
End Function

Function CheckTxt(txt)
Dim i As Integer
Dim Eng As Integer
Dim Chn As Integer
Chn = 0
Eng = 0
For i = 1 To Len(txt)
    If Asc(Mid(txt, i, 1)) > 0 Then
        Eng = 1
    Else:
        Chn = 1
    End If
Next i
If Chn = 1 And Eng = 1 Then   'Contains Both Eng & Chn
    CheckTxt = "BOTH"
Else:
    If Chn = 1 And Eng = 0 Then    'Chn
        CheckTxt = "CHN"
    Else:
        If Chn = 0 And Eng = 1 Then   'Eng
            CheckTxt = "ENG"
        End If
    End If
End If
End Function
```

The person who created them even supplied a file demonstrating how the functions work. I am attaching the link to the file which has the arrangement as follows:

```
Text|English part of it|Chinese part of it|ExtractEng|ExtractChn|CheckTxt
```

According to the author's intentions, the `CheckTxt` result should display either `CH`, `ENG`, or `BOTH`. However, it is only displaying `ENG` at all times and I cannot figure why.

Any ideas how to make it work? Unless there is an easier way to 'advance-filter' the content in Excel? Any help will be much appreciated.

[Test Excel file from the developer](https://a13d85c3-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/exceltkk2/excel-tutorial/howtoseparateenglishandchineseword-vbafunctionasc/HowtoSeparateEnglishandChineseWord-VBAFunctionASC.xls?attachauth=ANoY7cqrghw6DmqtRoV2yy-vfRFZz66oEa1e3NNrR-_PdS8Fe61NRntZGQQMAbBuEwSw48p0iDNLd-9TEXSDR90HF2dTfb_MQjtVC0RgHab1cBX6npR4Ng7Yla9lF-OOz7GXQkgNCVZgSoG_RXe9muQEoIiE6SyRRgZ12IXiIChY9UqFhxF7f9DoET_98d_lo6rS_UAE6McZuaVBGVCtT72MT0xogEwFiERKWkjivUQM28_qHfbymrYqHEH5sl2qD7fTCSwSVpZjbRT4EkWepOpzp9tCG6JXgDhLP8xGo-u0Twdrg0ZPBORElaHiXy4cAQ8ARKxZq6dXKuchA3JrLNuBObiHc8lyvtj2xjrmMq-Uux6dwxEfW44%3D&attredirects=0&d=1)

Comment: The code written by the original developer  expects your system to be using a [DBCS code page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317794(v=vs.85).aspx). On those systems, [Asc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264313.aspx) will return an negative integer for Chinese characters.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for Regular Expressions!!

[image]

```
Function getCharSet(Target As Range) As String
    Const ChinesePattern = "[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u6300-\u77FF\u7800-\u8CFF\u8D00-\u9FFF]+"
    Const EnglishPattern = "[A-Za-z]"
    Dim results As String
    Dim Data, v
    Dim Regex1 As Object
    Set Regex1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Regex1.Global = True

    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        Data = Array(Target.Value2)
    Else
        Data = Target.Value2
    End If

    For Each v In Data

        If Not InStr(results, "CHN") Then
            Regex1.Pattern = ChinesePattern
            If Regex1.Test(v) Then
                If Len(results) Then
                    getCharSet = "CHN" & " - " & results
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    results = "CHN"
                End If
            End If
        End If

        If Not InStr(results, "ENG") Then
            Regex1.Pattern = EnglishPattern
            If Regex1.Test(v) Then
                If Len(results) Then
                    getCharSet = results & " - ENG"
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    results = "ENG"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    getCharSet = results

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic approach :

```
Sub Main()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = sh.Range("A6:D10")

Call Separate_English_Chinese(rng)

End Sub

Sub Separate_English_Chinese(rng)

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = rng.Parent

Dim EnglishCharacters As String
Dim colEng As Long, colChn As Long, colContains As Long
Dim a As String, i As Long, k As Long
Dim colFullText As Long, txtEnglish As String, txtChinese As String
Dim Result As Long, Contains As String
Dim First As Long, Last As Long

First = rng.Row
Last = rng.Rows.Count + rng.Row - 1

EnglishCharacters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

EnglishCharacters = UCase(EnglishCharacters) & LCase(EnglishCharacters)

colFullText = 1
colEng = 2
colChn = 3
colContains = 4

For i = First To Last

    a = sh.Cells(i, colFullText).Value

    txtEnglish = ""
    txtChinese = ""

    For k = 1 To Len(a)

        If InStr(EnglishCharacters, Mid(a, k, 1)) Then
            txtEnglish = txtEnglish & Mid(a, k, 1)
        Else
            txtChinese = txtChinese & Mid(a, k, 1)
        End If

    Next

    sh.Cells(i, colEng).Value = txtEnglish
    sh.Cells(i, colChn).Value = txtChinese

    Result = 0
    If txtEnglish <> "" Then Result = Result + 1
    If txtChinese <> "" Then Result = Result + 10

    Select Case Result

        Case 1
        Contains = "ENG"
        Case 10
        Contains = "CHN"
        Case 11
        Contains = "BOTH"
        Case Else
        Contains = ""

    End Select

    sh.Cells(i, colContains).Value = Contains

Next

End Sub
```